# Are Android Package Names Copyrighted?

Tags: android, package-name

I am currently making an android app but I noticed that the domain in my package name is already taken, like if my package name is `com.mycompany.myapp` and the domain `mycompany.com` is taken, is it ok to leave it like that or will I get into problems for it?

Comment: If you name your package "tetris.ea" I think you'll get problems at some point since the play store will contain your package name in the public url pointing to your app (some kind of promotion using unauthorized licenced trademarks)

Comment: It's a legal question, not a technical one.